# Case-sensitive function names in Excel for Mac: how to switch off?

Tags: excel-formula

My Excel for mac 2011 doesn't understand function names typed in using lower case. For example:
This is working:

```
=SUM(A1:A10)
```

and this returns an Error with code `#NAME?`:

```
=sum(A1:A10)
```

The same time `=a1 + B1` will work properly.

The question is: how to make Excel case-insesitive?

*Some additional info: Mac OS X Yosemite, Excel for Mac 2011, Russian localization (cyrillic-based function names)*

Comment: What's more interesting, in Excel 2016 preview everything works properly.

Comment: Have you used "sum" as a named range in this particular workbook. Or, is this a macro enabled workbook and have you done any work in vba within the workbook where you may have used "sum" as an object name?

Comment: No, this is regular behavior in all (even in new ones) workbooks. Reinstall of the office gave me nothing.

Comment: By the way, functions with latin-based names work fine (I mean =cos(A1) will work, automatically switching to =COS(A1), but =sum(A1:A2) - with cyrillic function name [=сумм(A1:A2)] - will return an error #NAME.

Comment: In fact, after 2016 Office release the question is not of current importance anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that because you are using a localized version... on a Mac, the option for what you are looking for isn't available... yet. I think that you should go through the help documentation for the program to see if you can find it. If you can't, it probably isn't there.

Comment: ...But on my iMac everything works fine:) And the problem only occurs on my MacBookAir, with the same locale and the same version of Mac Os and Office...

Comment: Are both systems running the same version of the OS? If they are, then there should be nothing different between the two instances of Office provided they both have the same patches installed. The only other thing that could be different is processors and even then they are both likely to be x86 architecture Intels and the program would yield the same on both machines.

Comment: I understand this. And yet - there is a problem:)